# Mapping with Choropleth mapbox in python but figure does not display values correctly

Tags: python, mapping

I would like someone to help me in here...
I am having some trouble mapping. It apparently does not recognize the locations.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

I obtained the JSON file for Europe maps from GitHub and defined an "id" as the name of the country.

```
url_eu="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leakyMirror/map-of-europe/master/GeoJSON/europe.geojson"
with urlopen(url_eu) as response_eu:
eu_countries = json.load(response_eu)

for i in range(0,len(eu_countries['features'])):
               eu_countries['features'][i]['properties']['id'] = eu_countries['features'][i]['properties']['NAME']
```

This is the data I want to plot.

```
data = [['France', 10], ['Germany', 22], ['Italy', 5], ['Poland',7], ['Spain',8], ['United Kingdom',21]] 
df_map = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'count'])
```

This is the figure. However, it shows the colorscale correctly but it does not fill the selected countries with the data. So, at the end I have a blank map.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=eu_countries,
                                    locations=df_map['Country'],
                                    z=df_map['count'],
                                    colorscale='matter', zmin=0,
                                    colorbar_title = "Amazon warehouses",
                                    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0.2))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                      mapbox_zoom=3, mapbox_center = {"lat":  50 , "lon": 5})
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Do you know what is the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
add this line to the code before update_layout() line